# List all index using ismember

Tags: matlab, indexing

So say I have two arrays:

```
    A:14 63 13
      38 44 23
      11 12 13
      38 44 23

    B:38 44 23
```

I am trying to use `ismember`  to return the index  of every location where `B` is found in `A`. All examples I have found online only list the first or last occurrence of a match, I am trying to have a list indices for all values that match, even repeating ones. Thanks

Comment: do you expect the results `[2 4]` even if the `B` was `[38 23 44]`? you weren't clear about that!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html?refresh=true) with the `'rows'` arugment:

```
ismember(A, B, 'rows')
```

which results in a logical array `[0 1 0 1]` which is often better than an array of indices but if you want the indices specifically then just use `find`:

```
find(ismember(A,B,'rows'))
```

to return `[2,4]`

Note that this method will still work if `B` has multiple rows e.g. `B = [38 44 23; 11 12 13]`, it will return `[0; 1; 1; 1]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `bsxfun` for the comarison:

```
idx = find( all( bsxfun(@eq, A, B), 2 )); %// only where all line matches
```

Results with

```
idx =
 2
 4
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other." Is this because my A and B are different sizes? my A is size 345000x3 and B is size 19811x3.

Comment: @Dark your settings are **different** than those in your question! what do you expect for `A` and `B` of different sizes? Are you looking for all indices for each row of `B`?

Comment: @Dark, for these sizes of `A` and `B` use a `for` loop for each row of `B`. output `idx` into a cell array

Answer (score 3):

You can look into [`pdist2`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) if you have A and B as `Nx3` sized arrays -

```
[indA,indB] = ind2sub([size(A,1) size(B,1)],find(pdist2(A,B)==0));

ind = [indA,indB]
```

Thus, in `ind` you would have the pairwise indices for the matches with the first column representing the indices for `A` and the second one for `B`.

Sample run -

```
A =
    14    63    13
    38    44    23
    11    12    13
    14    63    13
    38    44    23
B =
    38    44    23
    14    63    13
ind =
     2     1
     5     1
     1     2
     4     2
```

Comment: `pdist2` solution very elegant in comparing row wise equality +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just an improved version of [shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621158/2111163) for handling multiple rows of `B`

```
idx = find(any(all( bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(B,[3 2 1])), 2 ),3));
```

**Sample Run:**

```
A = [14 63 13;
     38 44 23;
     11 12 13;
     38 44 23];

B = [38 44 23;
     11 12 13];

idx = find(any(all( bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(B,[3 2 1])), 2 ),3));

>> idx

idx =

 2
 3
 4
```